# SFDX CLI - How to Pull SObject Definitions from Salesforce Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am interested in knowing how someone can pull SObject definitions, custom and standard, from a scratch org using the CLI, or otherwise, into a local directory e.g. .sfdx. Something similar to what vscode plugin for Salesforce does.

Which commands are related? How can someone go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for `sfdx force:source:retrieve` command [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm).

For your own use case, you could run the following command:
`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Account`.

Note that this will work the same way the Metadata API works with a package.xml, as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm).

Definitely have a look to the *Wildcard Support in the Manifest File* section to understand what's retrieved with `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject` and what's not.